# Tableau - Conditions on LOD Expression

Tags: conditional-statements, tableau-api, level-of-detail

I have a purchase_log table which has the following fields:

uid, date, category, amount

And I would like to know the first and second purchases dates for each user of each category.

For example:

```
+-----+------+----------+--------+ 
| uid | date | category | amount |
+-----+------+----------+--------+
| A   | d1   | c1       | 100    |
| A   | d2   | c2       | 200    |
| A   | d3   | c1       | 120    |
| A   | d4   | c2       | 300    |
+-----+------+----------+--------+
```

For above user records, I would like to say the first purchase from category c1 is made on date d1, and second purchase from category c1 is made on date d3.

I currently created 3 calculated fields:

- 1st purchase:

  ```
  { FIXED [uid] : MIN([date])}
  ```
- Repeat purchase:

  ```
  IIF([date]>[1st Purchase],[date],null)
  ```
- 2nd purchase:

  ```
  { FIXED [uid] : MIN([Repeat Purchase])}
  ```

But since there is no distinction between categories, I'm not able to see dates with respect to categories.

How should I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by LODing on both uid and the category.

- 1st purchase:

  ```
  { FIXED [uid],[category] : MIN([date])}
  ```
- Repeat purchase:

  ```
  { FIXED [uid],[category]: IIF([date]>[1st Purchase],[date],null)}
  ```
- 2nd purchase:

  ```
  { FIXED [uid],[category] : MIN([Repeat Purchase])}
  ```

Comment: Hi Charlie, thank you for your answer. However on repeat purchase I'm getting "Result of a LOD expression must be an aggregate" error. How should I fix that?

Comment: @CanCeylan try { FIXED [uid],[category],[date]: IIF([date]>[1st Purchase],[date],null)}

Adding date to the LOD should reduce the granularity of aggregation to the date level.

Comment: tried that one as well, but still getting the same error and in underlines the IIF statement.

Comment: If you surround the IF statement with a function like MIN(), does it work/give you the proper  behavior?